# Facebook Pixel Error Message

Tags: facebook-pixel

I am trying to install a Facebook Pixel tracker on my website and for some reason it keeps giving me an error message saying "pixel did not load so no information was sent back to Facebook."

I copied the code exactly how they said to on Facebook onto my website in the main part of my wordpress website where the code would be applied to all pages and it saying a couple thing which I will attach a screen shot of it below.

Please help or let me know if I am not being descriptive enough for help. 
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNXz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goGPa.png)

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._ 
fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=
[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}
(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '1134776146627210'); // Insert your pixel ID here. 
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1134776146627210&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: Please post code but images, so that other can change, evolute and answer your question

Comment: Pretty sure those warnings mean that you are supposed to input _only_ JS code into that field - and not HTML. This does not seem to be the right place to embed more complex code snippets. There’s probably WordPress plugins out there to help embed the Facebook pixel, I’d suggest some research in that direction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is Javascript code because of the <script></script> tags. I did look into the plugins that offer pixel integration from Facebook but there are only so many tracking pixels and features they will track for free. To upgrade services it would cost a fee.

Comment: Also Yu Jiaao, I just added the code that Facebook asks me to copy and paste directly into my <head></head> tags. It looks like Javascript code because of the <script></script> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are its because you have some kind of ad blocker activated.